# Best foreign domain registrars?

Tags: domain-registration, domain-registrar

Does anyone have a preference for foreign domain registrars?

I am specifically interested in registering an .it domain. I understand that [Europe Registry](http://www.europeregistry.com/) provides this service (and allows one to acquire an Italian domain without having a business presence in the country,) but are their rates (EUR 49/yr) competitive?

From a legality standpoint, I have citizenship with a country in the EU, if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd first suggest http://eurodns.com as being *trustworthy* but also http://www.ovh.co.uk/domains/ for being cost-effective.

From a legal standpoint, as long as you abide by all of the rules and regulations, you should be fine.